# How to get list of all methods in a controller in cakephp3

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

In CakePhp2 we could get the list of methods in a controller in the following way:

```
App::import('Controller', 'TagsController');
$classMethods = get_class_methods('TagsController');
```

But in CakePhp3 App::import is not working. Then what's the way to get the list of methods of that controller in CakePHP3?

Thanks

Comment: Does `App::classname` work? [Reference](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html) Assume some sort of autoloader exists... can you just use `get_class_methods` but pass the full Controller class name?

Comment: @MushfiqurRahman if my answer helps you please accept it I have the upvote your question.

Answer (score 1):

Please pay attention to this link. I think the  `App::import()` changes to `App::classname()`

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/app.html

You can use this part.

```
// Names with \ in them will be returned unaltered.
App::classname('App\Cache\ComboCache');
// Returns App\Cache\ComboCache 
get_class_methods('App\Cache\ComboCache')
```

Comment: As the comment describes, that won't do anything, it would just return the very same string. If one has the fully qualified name of the controller class, then that's all that is needed for use with `get_class_methods()`, however not all methods returned by that function are controller actions...

Comment: @Aram Grigoryan I'm getting NULL in that way. Here's my code:
    $controller = $this->request->params['controller'];                
    App::classname($controller);                
    var_dump(get_class_methods($controller));exit; //gives NULL

Comment: @MushfiqurRahman can you write the result `$controller`  `(var_dump($controller))` please

Comment: `$controller` here will be something like simply "Tags". What you need to pass to `get_class_methods` would be more like "App\Controller\TagsController".

Comment: If the $controller name is TagsController then you should write App::classname ("App\Controller\".$controller) then get_classe_methods("App\Controller\".$controller)

Comment: Please can you write the result $controller and where it is

Comment: Also I think your $controller is not a string

Comment: I got my answer from @GregSchmidt's comment. No need to write `App::classname("App\Controller\".$controller);` Just writing the following line gives the list of all methods of the controller. `get_class_methods('App\Controller\'.$controller);` @AramGrigoryan Thanks for error effort. But it was better if would test the answer yourself first prior posting. Whatever thanks a lot. The final line of code is: `get_class_methods('App\Controller\\'.$controller.'Controller');` this is for those who would try by copy paste.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all method in a controller using php `ReflectionMethod` class

```
use ReflectionMethod;

public function getActions($controllerName) {
    $className = 'App\\Controller\\' . $controllerName . 'Controller';
    $class = new ReflectionClass($className);
    $actions = $class->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC);
    $controllerName = str_replace("\\", "/", $controllerName);
    $results = [$controllerName => []];
    $ignoreList = ['beforeFilter', 'afterFilter', 'initialize', 'beforeRender'];
    foreach ($actions as $action) {
        if ($action->class == $className
            && !in_array($action->name, $ignoreList)
        ) {
            array_push($results[$controllerName], $action->name);
        }
    }
    return $results;
}
```

If your want to get `Users` controller method list.  Then just call
`$this->getActions('Users')`

Hope it will help you.